# Android cursor getint null pointer exception

Tags: android, database, select, cursor

I have an app, where I try to select rows from database table if they exist. But I have an error in app. The table isn't empty, I inserted one row in table.

Code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    Cursor cursor = sqdb.rawQuery("SELECT _id, One, Two FROM TextView", null);
    if(cursor!= null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.test, null, false);
            tv1.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            tv2.setId(1000 - cursor.getInt(0));
            tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            tv2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            registerForContextMenu(tv1);
            registerForContextMenu(tv2);
        //((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(String.valueOf(i));
        //((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(String.valueOf(1000-i));

        ll.addView(v);
        }
    }
```

Logcat log:

```
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970): Your Message
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nightingale8/com.example.nightingale8.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at com.example.nightingale8.MainActivity.startNormalActivity(MainActivity.java:79)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at com.example.nightingale8.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
-    08-29 12:25:22.155: E/Your TAG(6970):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: which line  is point to line number 79 in main activity ?

Comment: Try to use cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow to get more accurate error log details.

Comment: @sunil tv1.setId(cursor.getInt(0));

Comment: tv1 is not added either in view or in linear layout and one more thing it gives integer value then set this way  tv1.setId(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0)));

Comment: @sunil same mistake, I think that trouble is in cursor or database, because when I tested on tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1)), I had the same mistake

Comment: do not try to use getInt() or getString(). Because it have more than column for int and string use this way    tv.setText(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

Comment: @sunil I tried to use this way before I used GetInt(), but it throwed the same mistake. Maybe something wrong with TextView?